# How to make counter stop count when he is below "1" using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, counter

need help, how to make my counter to stop the count when number is below  "1" ? I need to make the counter start only from '1' ( I have done this), and to restart to 1 when user click minus when amount is 1 )) After, i put my amount in a cart div, so I show the number of my products.  Here is my code:

```js
var plus = document.getElementById('plus');
var minus = document.getElementById('minus');
var amount = document.getElementById('amount');
var button2 = document.getElementById('add');
var cart = document.getElementById('cart'); 


  count = 1;

    plus.onclick = function() {
      count += 1;
      amount.innerHTML = count;
    };

   minus.onclick = function(){
       count-=1;
       amount.innerHTML =count;
    };
 
    button2.onclick = function(){
        cart.innerHTML = "products:" + count;
     }
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20pt;
  font-weight: normal;
  background: red;
  /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg, red, yellow);
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(-90deg, red, yellow);
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-90deg, red, yellow);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, red, yellow);
  /* Standard syntax */
}

.main {
  height: 200px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  padding: 20px 25px;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 18pt;
  border: 1px solid gold;
  color: yellow;
  outline: 0;
}
#add{
  
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

    <button id="minus">Minus</button>
    <div id="amount"> 1</div>
    <button id="plus">plus</button>
   
    
    <button id="add">add to cart</button>
    <div id="cart">products: </div>
    
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `if (count === 1) return;` to the beginning of your `minus.onclick` event:

```
minus.onclick = function() {
  if (count === 1) return;
  count -= 1;
  amount.innerHTML = count;
};
```

This way the rest of the function body won't be run when the `count` is 1. In other words, `count -= 1;` and the next line won't be run meaning that the `count` variable will not go below 1.

Note that `if (count === 1) return;` is the same as:

```
if (count === 1) {
  return;
}
```

Full code snippet:

```js
var plus = document.getElementById('plus');
var minus = document.getElementById('minus');
var amount = document.getElementById('amount');
var button2 = document.getElementById('add');
var cart = document.getElementById('cart'); 


    count = 1;

    plus.onclick = function() {
      count += 1;
      amount.innerHTML = count;
    };

    minus.onclick = function(){
      if (count === 1) return;
      count-=1;
      amount.innerHTML =count;
    };
 
    button2.onclick = function(){
      cart.innerHTML = "products:" + count;
    }
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20pt;
  font-weight: normal;
  background: red;
  /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg, red, yellow);
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(-90deg, red, yellow);
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-90deg, red, yellow);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, red, yellow);
  /* Standard syntax */
}

.main {
  height: 200px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  padding: 20px 25px;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 18pt;
  border: 1px solid gold;
  color: yellow;
  outline: 0;
}
#add{
  
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

    <button id="minus">Minus</button>
    <div id="amount"> 1</div>
    <button id="plus">plus</button>
   
    
    <button id="add">add to cart</button>
    <div id="cart">products: </div>
    
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your event click for `minus` and add the condition as below

```js
var plus = document.getElementById('plus');
var minus = document.getElementById('minus');
var amount = document.getElementById('amount');
var button2 = document.getElementById('add');
var cart = document.getElementById('cart'); 


  count = 1;

    plus.onclick = function() {
      count += 1;
      amount.innerHTML = count;
    };

   minus.onclick = function(){
       if(count>0){
       count-=1;
       amount.innerHTML =count;
       }
    };
 
    button2.onclick = function(){
        cart.innerHTML = "products:" + count;
     }
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20pt;
  font-weight: normal;
  background: red;
  /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg, red, yellow);
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(-90deg, red, yellow);
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-90deg, red, yellow);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, red, yellow);
  /* Standard syntax */
}

.main {
  height: 200px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  padding: 20px 25px;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 18pt;
  border: 1px solid gold;
  color: yellow;
  outline: 0;
}
#add{
  
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

    <button id="minus">Minus</button>
    <div id="amount"> 1</div>
    <button id="plus">plus</button>
   
    
    <button id="add">add to cart</button>
    <div id="cart">products: </div>
    
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 minus.onclick = function() {
   if (count > 1) {
     count-=1;
   }
   amount.innerHTML =count;
};
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Lwo6347z/